# Snort sfportscan does not log in unified2 file format

Tags: snort

I'm running Snort version 2.9.6.0 and I'm not able to log events from the sfportscan preprocessor using the unified2 file format.

This is the conf (actually is the default one):

```
preprocessor sfportscan: proto  { all } memcap { 10000000 } sense_level { medium }
```

If I add `logfile { /var/log/snort/portscan.log }` the events are correctly logged into the file.

My final goal is to show the sfportscan events into Snorby using barnyard2.